# The convergence of the improper integrals!

Tags: analysis

Suppose $f'(x)$ exists on $[0,\infty)$, prove or disprove that:
the following two integrals 
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2dx}{f(x)} \ 
\ \text{and}\ 
\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{f(x)+f'(x)}$$
have the same convergence.

Comment: Why are your questions almost always exclamations! :-)

Comment: Maybe He/she loves factorializing.

Comment: What measure do you use to say that his question almost always have exclamations? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. For a counterexample, use $f(x) = e^{-x}$ on $[0,1]$, $f(x) = e^{x}$ on $[2,\infty)$, and interpolate smoothly with a positive function on $[1,2]$. (Obviously here the problem is on $[0,1]$, not at $\infty$.)

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it! Thank you Pro. Lukas Geyer. I know you. I am also interested in Holomorphic Dynamics, especially the linearizable problem near the irrational fixed point of  rational maps.

Comment: I cannot understand it. We are assuming that $f'(x)\ge0$ right? How could we use $e^{-x}$? And I do not find this to be a counterexample. Could you tell me what I am missing? Thanks.